# Book where the people of this world are able to form special bonds with their dogs

Tags: story-identification

The book I'm looking for is the first in a series. The MC is a girl who lives in a slave village. Her people are seen as lesser and don't form bonds with the dogs. One day the girl meets one of the dogs and forms a bond with it. She later finds out it is due to her father being a part of the settlement of the people who form bonds with the dogs. This is about all I can remember about the plot.

Comment: Welcome Ashton. Please check-out our [story id checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and see if it doesn't jog your memory, then you can add some details - such as approximate year it was written, language it was in, any cover art or illustrations etc..